# Keep Browser waitng after Response.BinaryWrite command

Tags: asp.net, browser

I have an ASPX page that when the Browser navigates to returns some HTML. In some cases I want to return a file but have Browser continue waiting for HTML to return. I tried different things but as soon as Response.BinaryWrite executes the Browser gets a file downloaded and stops waiting. My question is it even remotely possible to do what I am trying to achieve?

What I am currently doing is that the returned HTML also downloads the file. That works fine but leaves the files on the server. I want to get rid of it right after the download is complete.

Thanks

Update

```
protected void ReportViewer1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // some code only relevant to reportviewer
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, you want to download a file, as part of the request, not the entire request?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In one shot. I would say download as a part of response.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest splitting it into two requests - I'm not sure that it's possible to return a file as part of the response.

Comment: Yeah, I wish I could split, not in the current architecture.

Comment: All I can think is maybe using the page load to trigger an ashx or something that returns the file in a new tab?

Comment: Not sure how I would  do that. Any example?

Comment: If you edit the relevant parts of your page load method from the codebehind your aspx page into the question, I'll see what I can do

Comment: I did add page load code. I didn't want to mention before it is about SSRS report viewer which is an aspx page.